# how to scraep text and image together?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a webpage scraper with beautifulSoup4. I want to get text and images of the article, but have some problems!
html code is sth like this:

```
<div>
 some texts1
 <br />
 <img src="imgpic.jpg" />
 <br />
 some texts2
</div>
```

I get the whole texts with this :

```
post_soup.get_text()
```

and save all images in `div` with `urllib2` as usual
finally I save them in a html page and put all text at top and images at last, but I want to save them in new html page just like the page I scraped them, I mean first `some texts1` then `image` then `some texts2`

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best and correct way, but it should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<div>\
 some texts1\
 <br />\
 <img src=\"imgpic.jpg\" />\
 <br />\
 some texts2\
</div>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = "+".join(soup.stripped_strings).split("+")

print text[0]
print soup.find("img")['src']
print text[1]
```

Output:

```
some texts1
imgpic.jpg
some texts2
```

Comment: +1 How could it be better? It gets multi-line strings on the top/bottom correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `get_text()`, I'd use [`prettify()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-encoding) to return the entire `<div>` section you want as a string.  This way you are always guaranteed to have the correct texts at the top and bottom. From there you can strip away parts of the string to get what you want:

```
# post_soup is the <div> element you posted
s = post_soup.prettify()
split_s = s.split('<br/>')
top = split_s[0].strip('<div>')
bottom = split_s[-1].strip('</div>')
```

Output:

```
>>> top
u'\n some texts1\n '
>>> bottom
u'\n some texts2\n'
```